# Android LunarLander and JetBoy Thread source

Tags: android

Hallo,

Is there a reason why the Thread class in the SDK LunarLander and JetBoy examples are not each in a separate java file, rather than being inside the View file?

It would make things a bit clearer, IMHO. Am I missing something?

- Frink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are bother inner classes so it allows them to share global variables

Comment: Ah, so in LunarLander, mContext is declared in LunarView, but used in LunarThread. mContext doesn't appear to be used in LunarView, other than the declaration so it's probably a bad example, but I see the point.

Answer (score 1):

Look at ReplicIsland source for a different example..

but the first step in thinking about is what is the DVM behavior  concerning a class when GC operates between a class in a separate file and a class in another class file..

Comment: DVM? GC? Sorry I'm not fully up to speed with the terminology yet.
Also, I'll have a look at ReplicaIsland, but is there any real reason for choosing one style/method over another?